# Intuitively, why does squaring a loss function change optimal values?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning

In many optimization problems, it is clear that by performing a non-linear operation we change the outcome of any potential optimal values.

For example in machine learning: summing over **errors** (manhattan distance) vs **squared errors** (euclidean distance)

$$
\sum|x-y|$$
$$
\sum(x-y)^2$$

However, intuitively I am having trouble answering why this is the case. A voice in the back of my head keeps saying

> bigger numbers will get bigger and smaller numbers will get smaller,
>   thus, the biggest number will still be the biggest and the smallest number
>   will still be the smallest.

I know this is not the case, but can someone offer some insight and examples into perhaps why?

Comment: Manhattan distance would be $\sum|x-y|$, not $\sum(x-y)$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you square before summing, the big errors have more weight and pull the fit harder in their direction.  As a specific example, suppose we have the data $\{0,1,2,3,10\}$ and want to find the best fit.  If we use the sum of the absolute errors we get the median, $2$.  If we use the sum of the squared errors we get the mean, $\frac{16}5$.  Minimizing the squared errors corresponds nicely (in the very unlikely case that the error distribution is normal) to maximizing the probability that the fitted values are correct.

Comment: The layman's explanation that you started off with clicked with me very easily.

Answer (score 2):

Think about finding a point on the real line that's as close as possible to the points $0$ and $1$. If you use a sum of manhattan distances, you get
$$
D(x) = |x-0| + | 1 - x |.
$$

For any $x$ between $0$ and $1$, the value of $D(x)$ is exactly 1. Outside that interval, $D$ is always greater than 1. So: manhattan distance gives you many many optima.

Now look at 
$$
E(x) = (x-0)^2 + (1 - x)^2.
$$

$E$ is evidently minimized at $x = 0.5$, so there's a unique optimum, and it's nicely "balanced" between the two anchor points.

Everything you need to know is really contained in this one example; it's worth a bit of study.